# Checking for gcc compile error in Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, gcc

How can you compile using the gcc command within a batch script and check if there was an error.
It would look something like this, except it doesn't work:

```
set ERROR=gcc source.c -Wall -o output.exe
if ERROR (
    pause
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc source.c -Wall -o output.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    pause
)
```

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That doesn't work if the program returns a negative status code.

Comment: You could also use `gcc source.c -Wall -o output.exe || pause`